# React Router (v3) redirect not redirecting to new location

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have a router setup like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {IndexRoute, NotFoundRoute, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import Home from './components/Home';
import AuthorPage from './components/authors/AuthorPage';
import About from './components/about/About';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="authors" component={AuthorPage} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      <Redirect from="/about-us" to="/about" />
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Everything but the redirecting works fine. Whenever I try to navigate to `/about-us`, I get a white page displaying `Cannot GET /about-us`.

Cannot seem to find anything about this in the docs. Does the "from" part of the route still have to exist for this to work, or should it just redirect me regardless?

EDIT:

I should also mention that I use the history package, as mentioned in the react-router upgrade guide: `https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md`

Here is my main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Router from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

// Using history to avoid default behavior of weird urls like `?_k=umhx1s`
// See:  https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md
let history = createBrowserHistory();
const root = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, root);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the order of my routes were wrong. My "catch all" NotFound-route needed to be placed after my redirect for this to work.

```
import React from 'react';
import {IndexRoute, NotFoundRoute, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import Home from './components/Home';
import AuthorPage from './components/authors/AuthorPage';
import About from './components/about/About';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App} >
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="authors" component={AuthorPage} />
    <Redirect from="about-us" to="about" /> // Switched order with below Route.
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your having a typo right there. In your routes you have `<Route path="about" component={About} />` notice that you have `path="about"` and you are trying to navigate to `/about-us`. That won't match to any of your route. Try navigating to `/about` or change your routes to `<Route path="about-us" component={About} />`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I tried your first suggestion with the `/`, but I'll take a look again tomorrow when I get back to work. In the meantime, how come the docs / changelog doesn't mention this (Your second suggestion, referring to  `component={About}`)? https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md (See the part on Redirects) :)

Comment: So, I've tried your suggestion and it doesn't work :( Looks like redirecting in general is an issue for some reason. I've tried redirecting between existing pages as well, but no luck. Still get the white page saying `cannot GET /component-name`

Comment: I figured this out finally. Turns out that my 'catch all' NotFound route needs to be defined after my redirect for this to work :)